# Server space issue : how to merge drives

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, dev

my server is having space issue below is what is see when using **df -h**, my space of **/dev/m2** is getting fulled say 99% frequently and it causes issue with my sessions and all , i want merge **/dev/m3** with **/dev/m2** or is there way i can move code and all to m3 so i do not get space issue

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           252G  4.0G  248G   2% /run
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2         20G   18G  566M  97% /
/dev/sda1       510M  152K  510M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md3        3.6T   70M  3.4T   1% /home
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when default storage partitioning is used without thinking about capacity planning or layout.

---

Plan a storage migration to LVM. Test your backup restores. Create new volume groups for your data. Create new logical volumes and file systems. Only as big as needed: if you have a 5 GB `/srv` only make that say 10 GB to start.

How you accomplish this migration is very dependent if you have a secondary system on different storage, and the storage you have available. As `/home` is underutilized, one way:

- take downtime
- `umount /home`
- create a volume group on home's former storage (`/dev/md3`)
- create correctly-sized  logical volumes and file systems
- restore backup of `/home`